# The effect of reading news on a topic you know, understanding it is misleading at best - and what this says about all other news stories

Tags: bias

Sometimes you will read a news-article, and because you have deep knowledge about the topic of the article, you understand that the articles is at best half-truth - but quite often just plain wrong and filled with factual mistakes.

This means you could reasonably assume all the other stories are similarly inaccruate.

What is the name of this effect?

I recently found out there was a name for this effect. Unfortunately I did not make a note of it, and my google searches on the topic have been fruitless - so I am hoping somebody here will know the right term.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the indicated question. That question is about the [Gell-Mann Amnesia - Epsilon Theory](https://www.epsilontheory.com/gell-mann-amnesia/), which is almost the opposite of what is asked about here, the failure to "*reasonably assume all the other stories are similarly inaccruate*".

Comment: Partial answer: I've referred to this as "The Budrys Test", because I first heard of it in an article by author Algis Budrys.  He was reviewing a biographical encyclopedia that contained an article about himself, and used the accuracy of that article to judge the reliability of the other biographies in the book.